# Why is a match pattern with a guard clause not exhaustive?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Consider the following code sample ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=d253c4332ae64bb3e4371c19b4ccd264)).

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
enum State {
    Initial,
    One,
    Two,
}

enum Event {
    ButtonOne,
    ButtonTwo,
}

struct StateMachine {
    state: State,
}

impl StateMachine {
    fn new() -> StateMachine {
        StateMachine {
            state: State::Initial,
        }
    }

    fn advance_for_event(&mut self, event: Event) {
        // grab a local copy of the current state
        let start_state = self.state.clone();

        // determine the next state required
        let end_state = match (start_state, event) {
            // starting with initial
            (State::Initial, Event::ButtonOne) => State::One,
            (State::Initial, Event::ButtonTwo) => State::Two,

            // starting with one
            (State::One, Event::ButtonOne) => State::Initial,
            (State::One, Event::ButtonTwo) => State::Two,

            // starting with two
            (State::Two, Event::ButtonOne) => State::One,
            (State::Two, Event::ButtonTwo) => State::Initial,
        };

        self.transition(end_state);
    }

    fn transition(&mut self, end_state: State) {
        // update the state machine
        let start_state = self.state.clone();
        self.state = end_state.clone();

        // handle actions on entry (or exit) of states
        match (start_state, end_state) {
            // transitions out of initial state
            (State::Initial, State::One) => {}
            (State::Initial, State::Two) => {}

            // transitions out of one state
            (State::One, State::Initial) => {}
            (State::One, State::Two) => {}

            // transitions out of two state
            (State::Two, State::Initial) => {}
            (State::Two, State::One) => {}

            // identity states (no transition)
            (ref x, ref y) if x == y => {}

            // ^^^ above branch doesn't match, so this is required
            // _ => {},
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut sm = StateMachine::new();

    sm.advance_for_event(Event::ButtonOne);
    assert_eq!(sm.state, State::One);

    sm.advance_for_event(Event::ButtonOne);
    assert_eq!(sm.state, State::Initial);

    sm.advance_for_event(Event::ButtonTwo);
    assert_eq!(sm.state, State::Two);

    sm.advance_for_event(Event::ButtonTwo);
    assert_eq!(sm.state, State::Initial);
}
```

In the `StateMachine::transition` method, the code as presented does not compile:

```
error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `(Initial, Initial)` not covered
  --> src/main.rs:52:15
   |
52 |         match (start_state, end_state) {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pattern `(Initial, Initial)` not covered
```

But that is exactly the pattern I'm trying to match! Along with the `(One, One)` edge and `(Two, Two)` edge. Importantly I specifically want this case because I want to leverage the compiler to ensure that every possible state transition is handled (esp. when new states are added later) and I know that identity transitions will always be a no-op.

I can resolve the compiler error by uncommenting the line below that one (`_ => {}`) but then I lose the advantage of having the compiler check for valid transitions because this will match on any states added in the future.

I could also resolve this by manually typing each identity transition such as:

```
(State::Initial, State::Initial) => {}
```

That is tedious, and at that point I'm just fighting the compiler. This could probably be turned into a macro, so I could possibly do something like:

```
identity_is_no_op!(State);
```

Or worst case:

```
identity_is_no_op!(State::Initial, State::One, State::Two);
```

The macro can automatically write this boilerplate any time a new state is added, but that feels like unnecessary work when the pattern I have written should be covering the exact case that I'm looking for.

1. Why doesn't this work as written?
2. What is the cleanest way to do what I am trying to do?

---

I have decided that a macro of the second form (i.e. `identity_is_no_op!(State::Initial, State::One, State::Two);`) is actually the preferred solution.

It's easy to imagine a future in which I do want some of the states to do something in the 'no transition' case. Using this macro would still have the desired effect of forcing the state machine to be revisited when new `State`s are added and would just require adding the new state to the macro arglist if nothing needs to be done. A reasonable compromise IMO.

I think the question is still useful because the behavior was surprising to me as a relatively new Rustacean.

Comment: While in this simple case the compiler theoretically _could_ figure out what cases are covered by the guard, this is not possible in general.  The guard can contain arbitrary expressions, function calls and references to external state, so in the general case the compiler can't know whether the guard condition holds.  For this reason, Rust always assumes that it might _not_ hold, even if the guard is `if true`, which makes the semantics simple and predictable.

Comment: @Stargateur, no I didn’t say it myself, and yes I did clearly explain what I’m trying to do. I want to catch every case where the start_state and end_state are equal.

Comment: @Sven thanks that makes sense, I guess I hoped it could exhaust this simple case.

Comment: @MichaelLeonard So what the problem with `(State::Initial, State::Initial) | (State::One, State::One) | (State::Two, State::Two) => {}` ? That what I will do. The solution is already at the end of your question. Use a macro or write it at the hand.

Comment: @Stargateur, it works but it is tedious (and I was just curious why this didn't work). I expect this state machine to grow to contain 100's of states. With that said I have, for other reasons, decided that the second macro I suggested is actually the better solution anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work as written?

Because the Rust compiler cannot take guard expressions into account when determining if a `match` is exhaustive.  As soon as you have a guard, it assumes that guard could fail.

Note that this has nothing to do with the distinction between [refutable and irrefutable patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-02-refutability.html).  `if` guards are *not* part of the pattern, they're part of the `match` syntax.

> What is the cleanest way to do what I am trying to do?

List every possible combination.  A macro *could* slightly shorten writing the patterns, but you can't use macros to replace entire `match` arms.

Comment: Or add a `_ => unreachable!()` if you are confident that you are doing it right.

Comment: @rodrigo, no I want to avoid the catch-all pattern in order to force the match statement to be updated if new states are added later. I’m confident I’m doing it correctly now, but trying to protect against future changes. And furthermore, the pattern isn’t 'unreachable!()', it’s valid to call this function with the two states equal, I just don’t want it to do anything.

Comment: @MichaelLeonard As a general remark, of course it's best if the compiler can check your invariants statically.  If it can't, your next best option is a unit test. You'd need to use the `EnumIter` derive macro from the `strum` crate to be able to iterate over all variants of the enum, but you would also need `_ => unreachable!()` to panic if the catch-all branch is entered.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, that's a good suggestion. That would clearly work in this example case, but the actual use case is a rust-embedded project which requires no_std crates, and I'm not sure if `cargo test` even works in that situation (haven't tried it yet).

Comment: @DK. please update your answer to refer to refutable vs. irrefutable patterns and I will accept it. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-02-refutability.html

Comment: @MichaelLeonard The tests would still be allowed to depend on `std`, right?  I mean, the tests are run on the development machine, not on the embedded device.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yes the test harness can still depend on std, but testing the state machine would in general be a pretty hopeless endeavor since it is so closely tied to the hardware (I would need another engineer to write a hardware mock). However, I could probably just test for this condition, and do plan to add test cases for other things that don't depend on the hardware. I'll play with the idea today.

Comment: @DK. wait, I guess I'm still confused then. The core problem _is_ refutability isn't it? The match guard is not part of the pattern but it does **make the pattern refutable**, therefore this arm can't be used by rust to reliably declare the pattern as exhaustive.

Comment: @MichaelLeonard: The pattern was *already* refutable.  The issue is that the *guard* can fail, even if the pattern matches.