# Non-exhaustive match i32 even if it is

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Rust compiler complains about the following match being non-exhaustive. Is it a limit of Rust or do I miss something?

```
fn main() {
  let x = 10;
  match x {
     1 => {},
     y if y < 1 => {},
     y if y > 1 => {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust won't process `if` expressions when validating exhaustiveness. Given that, you would either need to add a catch-all match that you mark as unreachable, e.g.

```
fn main() {
  let x = 10;
  match x {
    1 => {},
    y if y < 1 => {},
    y if y > 1 => {}
    _ => unreachable!()
  }
}
```

or given your logic, the better option would be to not include the last `if` at all, e.g.

```
fn main() {
  let x = 10;
  match x {
    1 => {},
    y if y < 1 => {},
    y => {}
  }
}
```

because it will only reach the last `match` if the earlier one fails.

Related:

- [Why is a match pattern with a guard clause not exhaustive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166245/why-is-a-match-pattern-with-a-guard-clause-not-exhaustive)

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner but more verbose alternative is to use three-way comparison via [`cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#tymethod.cmp):

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;
 
match x.cmp(&1) {
    Ordering::Less => { /* ... */ },
    Ordering::Equal => { /* ... */ },
    Ordering::Greater => { /* ... */ },
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2b70b56e78dcc4950a5c89964bc0c30))

The exhaustiveness of the match is checked by the compiler.  In particular, the `cmp` method is unavailable for types that implement `PartialOrd` but not `Ord`, so the failure to handle incomparable values will be caught at compile time.

This is mentioned in the [Comparing the Guess to the Secret Number](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#comparing-the-guess-to-the-secret-number) section of the [Programming a Guessing Game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#programming-a-guessing-game) chapter in the book.

Answer (score -2):

If I interpret the question correctly you should be able to capture rest of the numbers by using `_` as mentioned in https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html

A sample use can be the following

```rust
match x {
    1 => println!("one"),
    _ => ()
}
```